# Make numerical floats in the same unit in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series (float64) with the following problem:

```
series = pd.Series([3.65, 37.8, 0.3800, 3.9, 3.10, 3111.12, np.nan, 0.32, 3.3, 3.4 ])
```

How I can make all these floats consistent (i.e have the same scale/unit)?

The expected result in this case should be:

```
series_corrected = pd.Series([3.65, 3.78, 3.800, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11112, np.nan, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like below with string edit, but which will depends on your real data

```
s = series.astype(str).str.findall('\d+').str.join('').str.strip('0')
s = pd.to_numeric(s.str[0]+'.'+s.str[1:],errors='coerce')
s
0    3.65000
1    3.78000
2    3.80000
3    3.90000
4    3.10000
5    3.11112
6        NaN
7    3.20000
8    3.30000
9    3.40000
dtype: float64
```